# Why does fread not read into uint16_t value properly?

Tags: c, fread

When trying to read in a signature from a bmp file, and after calling fread, `sig`contains `52428`Note this is `0xCCCC` instead of `19778`, which is the proper decimal value for `0x4D42` or `'BM'` which is the proper header signature for a BMP file.

```
uint16_t sig;
// 0. If any of the operations fail, free any memory and return 0

// 1. Open the file
FILE *f = fopen(file, "r");
if (f == 0) {
    printf("Cannot open file\n");
}

// 2a. Read the initial fields of the header; verify that the file type (BM) is correct.
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
fread(&sig, sizeof(uint16_t), 1, f); // signature
printf("%d\n", sig);
if (sig != 0x4D42) {
    printf("not a bmp file!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I tried reading in one byte at a time using uint8_t, as well as many other solutions to fixing this problem.

It seems like `fread` is just not properly writing to `sig` because `CC` is the default format for uninitialized memory using the compiler that I am using. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the bmp file that I'm trying to read in:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZuOS.jpg)

Comment: Why aren't you checking the return value of `fread()`.?

Comment: Maybe you should exit if the file was not opened.

Comment: @Bobby: So, did you check your output for "Cannot open file" message?

Comment: @drescherjm Or more precisely stop reading from the file.

Comment: Is '%d' the correct format specifier for uint16_t?

Comment: @MartinJames if `int` is 32-bit or larger, it is

Comment: In the `f == 0` branch you should actually abort in some way , rather than going on to fseek (which would cause undefined behaviour)

Comment: Your code should work like that. what compiler are you using and can you provide the BMP file you are trying to open?

Comment: @iharob the return value of fread() is 0 which means it's not even reading in the 2 bytes

Comment: @Flikk I'm runnig this on visual studio 2015

Comment: @bobby open your BMP in https://hexed.it/?hl=en and check if the sig is really `'bm'`

Comment: @bobby can you use a hex editor to confirm that the first bytes of your BMP file are `'BM'`?

Comment: @bobby: the link you provided is a JPG file, so it is presumably not the actual BMP file you are working with. Looking at the picture doesn't help much, although it is a pretty autumnal view.

Comment: @bobby it would be enough to confirm the sig of the file with a hex editor like https://hexed.it/?hl=en and try what Sahu said. Initialize sig to zero. And check the return value of fread to make sure that the operation was successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code totally should work. You're allocating 2 bytes for `sig` and then reading 2 bytes into it from the beginning of the file correctly. As long as these first two bytes are `BM`or '0x4D42' then you should be good.

**My guess is that the issue lies with your directory/file paths.**

Check to make sure that the file you are passing in has the correct filepath. Note that to pass it with a relative filepath you will need to make the filepath relative to the project's root directory.

Hope this helps!

Comment: He is opening something. Otherwise i'd expect a segmentation fault. I'd say he is opening a file that is not a BMP

Comment: Why do you insist he is opening something? It's not in mode "r+" and it seems like the memory at the location is still uninitialized

Comment: OMG!  My bmp files were in my project folder, but my .cpp and .h files were in a different folder this entire time.  Everything works perfectly now!  When I print the value of sig, I get 19778 which is exactly what I need THANK YOU

Comment: Shouldn't it have printed `Cannot open file` if he gave the wrong paths?

Comment: Yeah, it's unclear if it was printing that, because it definitely should have if the file didn't exist, as `f==0` would have returned true. perhaps the file was created sometime in the process, and so there was the correctly named file of whatever was being passed in but it was empty? Kinda hard to tell but you're correct it should have.

Comment: So, all this boils down to 'didn't specify the path right'?

Comment: And the code did not properly handle the error conditions. Hopefully that part was fixed because just adjusting the path is not the whole solution.

Comment: Right, there's still a couple of shortcomings in the code snippet, but yeah, it did basically boil down to double checking the file paths it seems, as the code should have been doing what he expected, however project management and not the code was the silent killer here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file exists, you should know that you're opening the file as text, instead of binary.

Try:

```
FILE *f = fopen(file, "rb");
```

Comment: It's a nice observation but I doubt this would help.

Comment: On Unix there's no difference between `r` and `rb`. On Windows, I think it only affects how newlines are treated.

Comment: @barmar: It also causes EOF to be mysteriously signalled if the binary file contains the byte `0x1A`.

Comment: @rici good point. but since the file should start with `0x424D`, this should not be relevant for the problem. But i agree, it should be changed to  `fopen(file, "rb");`

Comment: @flikk: agreed, but it is a useful fact to know :)

Answer (score 1):

I would try couple of things:

1. Initialize `sig` to zero.
2. Check the return value of `fread` to make sure that the operation was successful.

If nothing comes of that, the next thing to try would be use

```
char sig[2];

...

if ( 2 != fread(sig, 1, 2, f) ) { ...
```

Comment: While this is a good idea, there's no reason why `fread()` would fail unless the file was too short. That's not likely to be the case for his `.bmp` file.

Comment: @Barmar, nothing else seemed to be a problem in the posted code.

Comment: I think initializing `sig` seems to be the most likely solution. It's a non standard type and that does not look good.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and i have no problems.
Can you provide the BMP file you want to read?

Also here i have written some code for you that might help you to keep everything organized if thid project gets bigger. i suggest putting the structs into a header file.

edit: had to define the data types in the structs myself since i did this in an environment that did not have `stdint.h`. sorry. But you can just change them.

you can use these structs to store your header informations:

```
typedef struct {
    uint16  Signature;
    uint32  Size;
    uint16  Reserved1;
    uint16  Reserved2;
    uint32  BitsOffset;
} BITMAP_FILE_HEADER;

typedef struct {
    uint32  biSize;
    int32   biWidth;
    int32   biHeight;
    uint16  biPlanes;
    uint16  biBitCount;
    uint32  biCompression;
    uint32  biSizeImage;
    int32   biXPelsPerMeter;
    int32   biYPelsPerMeter;
    uint32  biClrUsed;
    uint32  biClrImportant;
} BITMAP_INFO_HEADER;

typedef struct {
    uint32  bcSize;
    uint16  bcWidth;
    uint16  bcHeight;
    uint16  bcPlanes;
    uint16  bcBitCount;
} BITMAP_CORE_HEADER;
```

Using this function to read the header

```
int read_header(FILE* inputfile, BITMAP_INFO_HEADER* header, BITMAP_FILE_HEADER* fHeader) {
    BITMAP_FILE_HEADER fileHeader;
    BITMAP_INFO_HEADER infoHeader;
    BITMAP_CORE_HEADER coreHeader;
    uint32 headersize;

    fread(&fileHeader.Signature, sizeof(fileHeader.Signature), 1, inputfile);
    printf("%d", fileHeader.Signature);
}
```

And use the main function to call everything and handle the errors

```
int main(void) {
    FILE* inputfile = NULL;
    BITMAP_INFO_HEADER infoHeader = {0};
    BITMAP_FILE_HEADER fileHeader = {0};

    if ( (inputfile = fopen("source.bmp", "rb")) == NULL ) {
        ERROR("can't open file.")
        return 1;
    }

    if ( read_header(inputfile, &infoHeader, &fileHeader) == 0 ) {
        ERROR("Fileformat not supported.")
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Depending on what you allocate, you can use an `ERROR()` macro to clear everything like:

```
#define ERROR(ErrMsg) \
    printf("Error: %s\n", ErrMsg); \
    if (bitmapData != NULL) \
        free(bitmapData); \
    if (yourAlloc != NULL) \
        free(yourAlloc);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and also relies on a number of implementation details (e.g. struct packing, and integer endianness)

Comment: @M.M yes, i think i got carried a little away when testing it. But maybe it will be helpful for him if he continues. I couldnt find any problems with his code either. So for further testing we need to know how he compiles it and  also need his BMP file for testing.

Comment: @Flikk I added the image link at the bottom of the post

Comment: @Bobby that's a JPEG. Starting with `0xFFD8`

Answer (score -1):

Here is the Solution try to understand it,Feel free to ask if you have any doubt.

Remember the first two bytes of BMP Should always be `'B'` followed '`M'` or `hex` values `0x42` and `0x4D` or `int(8 bit)` values `66`  and `77`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   FILE *fp = NULL;
   int fsize,result;
   char *buffer = NULL;

   fp = fopen("fileName.bmp", "rb+");
   if (fp == NULL)
   {
     printf( "Error! File Not found!\n");
   }
   else
   {
      fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
      fsize = ftell(fp);
      fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
      printf("File Size:%d\n",fsize);

      buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*fsize);
      result=fread(buffer, sizeof(char), fsize, fp);

      if (result != fsize)
      {
         printf("Error Reading file!\n");
      }
      fclose(fp);
   }

   //Remember the first two bytes of BMP Should always be
   //'B' followed 'M' or hex values 0x42 and 0x4D or int(8 bit) values 66  and 77
   if (buffer[0] == 'B' && buffer[1] == 'M')
   {
     printf("File is BMP!\n");
   }
   else
   {
     printf("Not BMP!\n");
   }

   free(buffer);
   buffer = NULL;

   return 0;
}
```

if you want int(8 bit) values of the bmp file then you can add the following code lines,

```
char *buffer = NULL;
int *fdata = NULL;

//Get the file size as in above code and after that
buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*fsize);
fdata =  malloc(sizeof(int)*fsize);

result=fread(buffer, sizeof(char), fsize, fp);
if (result != fsize)
{
   printf("Error Reading file!\n");
}

for (int i = 0; i < fsize; i++)
{
    if (buffer[i] < 0)
    {
        fdata[i] = 256 + (int)buffer[i];
    }
    else
    {
        fdata[i] = (int)buffer[i];
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < fsize; i++)
{
    printf("%d ",fdata[i]);
}

//free up after your done
free(buffer);
buffer=NULL;
free(fdata);
fdata=NULL;
```

Comment: Did you try to execute Bobbys code? Because it is working. Then you are using c++ for a c question. I'd say there is something wrong with his compiler / compiler settings or his BMP file

Comment: 1. Your code cannot be compiled with a [tag:c] compiler, [tag:c] and [tag:c++] are not the same. 2. You are using mandatory casts for `malloc()` but since it's c++ you should use c++ style casts.3. You never check the return value of `malloc()`. 4. If for some reason `fread()` reads less bytes than expected your code dereferences a `NULL` pointer. I could go on but I don't want to read your code anymore.

Comment: @Flikk Sorry I didn't go through his question properly. I tested his code it shows the correct value if i load a bmp image. And it shows some other values if it is not bmp file. You are right there must be something wrong with his compiler or his bmp file.

Comment: @iharob  I actually wrote the code in C++(VS) but then I saw the OP had written his code in C so i thought it would be better if i also answered it in C. So, I converted my code to C but I guess I forgot about changing the last 'cout' statement.And thanks for pointing out the malloc() mistakes. It's been a while since I wrote in C.